# Create Options dynamically from table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to fill #sku_dropdown dynamically with the data in the first column. I also want the option "New Sku" to allow you to type your own option in.

FORM

```html
  <form>
 <select id="sku_dropdown">
<option disabled selected value>Select Sku</option>
<option>New Sku</option>
</select>
 <input class="button" id="submit_log" name="submit_log" value="Submit Log" type="button" />
</form>
```

TABLE

```html
<table id="table">

</table>
```

ADD ROW & DATA

```
function submitLog() {
  let tableRefLog = document.getElementById('table');
  let newRowLog = tableRefLog.insertRow(-1);
  let newCellBlank = newRowLog.insertCell(0);
  let newCellSku = newRowLog.insertCell(1);
  let sku = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('#sku_dropdown').value);
newCellSku.appendChild(sku);

document.getElementById('submit_log').onclick = submitLog;
```

Comment: What are you specifically stuck on? What have you tried to make this work?

Comment: Getting the select options to be dynamically created from the column data. I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I'm not sure where the column data is coming from, but you could append an ``<option value=""></option>`` from right inside of the submitLog where the data is processed.

Comment: @grant Noe column data comes when you add row & data